# Update fields just before approval

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, flow, approval-process, power-automate

Here's the flow I'm trying to create:

1. A user creates a request (SharePoint list)
2. The controller approves the request.
3. The controller fill two extra fields.
4. COO approves
5. Purchasing Office is notified

Can I have the two fields I need to be updated by the controller to appear in the approval email or something like that?

Comment: Those values can be displayed in the email, but they wouldn't be able to update them directly from email.  Easiest way is to put a hyperlink in the email to the item's built-in Edit Form.  There is also a new feature still in "Preview" mode called Flow UI, that would allow you to build a simple form as part of your Flow, if you have Preview-mode features enabled in your tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Flow approval action does not provide custom fields for users to fill in. The possible approach may be add the link to item and provide notifications saying like "please fill in the extra 2 columns" 
[image]